# Use masks to evaluate bits of a uint512

Tags: c++, operators, bit

If I met something like this:

```
uint32_t mask = 8;
uint32_t zero = 0;
uint32_t foo[16];
...
if ((foo[0] & mask) != zero)
...
```

the condition simply checks the first 8 bits of foo[0], which is a 32-bit unsigned int.

If I have the same value previously stored into foo[16] now into an uint512 variable, **how can I get the same condition?**

Since foo[0] is the first slot of the vector, it means I previously checked the first 8 bits of the first slot, so can I simply use this?

```
if (("uint512 variable" & mask) != zero)
```

Comment: The condition does *not* check the first 8 bits of `foo[0]`, it only checks bit 4. If you want to check the 8 first bits, then use e.g. `0xff`.

Comment: What type is `uint512`? A 512 bit unsigned integer?

Comment: Also, while it's good to avoid "magic numbers", comparing a bit-operation against the *literal* zero (i.e. `0`) is generally acceptable. Using *variables* for constants like zero will in the future earn you a place on http://thedailywtf.com/

Comment: Regarding your "uint512 variable", you have *no* such variable. You have a variable which consists of 16 separate `uint32_t` members. Those can not be combined into a single 512-vit entity without special functions to handle just that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Zero is not special. Just don't use variables where the name of the variable directly indicates the value. `const int ten = 10;` is just as bad as `const int zero = 0;`. `const int minimum_size = 0;`, on the other hand, may sometimes be a good constant.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

> the condition simply checks the first 8 bits of foo[0], which is a 32-bit
>   unsigned int.

I think you mean the first 32 bits — `foo[0]` is the first element which is a 32-bit holder.

Assuming there is `uint512`, I don't understand what exactly do you want to accomplish, but I think it's one of two things:

1. Check all uint512 as a single entity using a 512-bit mask like this:

   ```
   uint512_t mask = 8;
   uint512_t zero = 0;
   uint512_t foo;
   ...
   if ((foo & mask) != zero)
   ...
   ```
2. Check an 8-bit slice of the 512-bit variable. In this case you can't simply get it as they array version. This is because depending on the endianness of the target machine, the first 8-bit may be the most significant or the least significant 8-bits.

If you want to check the most significant bits:

```
uint32_t mask = 8;
uint32_t zero = 0;
uint512_t foo;
...
if ((uint32_t)(foo >> 480) & mask) != zero)
...
```

If you want to check the least significant bits:

```
uint32_t mask = 8;
uint32_t zero = 0;
uint512_t foo;
...
if (((uint32_t)foo & mask) != zero)
...
```

Comment: basically i am adapting a part of code not written by me. The old code contains an uint32_t vector containing an hash (splitted between 16 * 32bit slots i supposed). My code has instead a uint512 variable containing that hash. What i need is get the same result from the condition "If ((foo[0] & mask) != 0)", using my uint512 variable instead of foo[0]. if i well understand your answer, it seems i can simply use "if (("my uint512" & mask) != 0)" to get the same result of the old "if" conditional.